React: The input bar is colliding with the results box
I have a modal that contains two components: an input field and a results box. When the modal opens, these components collide. Both components are written in React. Unfortunately, I can't share the code and I can't reproduce the issue with an open-source component.
Any ideas on how to debug and fix this issue would be appreciated.


Please share the reproduction with an open-source component.

Without any code it'll be difficult. Looks to me that the results box is is being positioned by JS to location that the Search bar is initially, then the animation plays for the Search bar to move and the results box is lagging behind to move along with it.
Consider adding a delay to have the results box only displayed after the Search bar is done animating.
